# Can we isolate an Object from a Force field?

Tags: objects, particles, force-fields

For my character Hair, I have set wind (1 & 2) at different directions. I do not want my cloths to interact with this wind(1 & 2), but another wind(3) setup that would only affect cloth but not Hair. Is this possible or any better ways to manage it?

Comment: I found a way, maybe one of the way. Basically add all the objects and respective force field into a collection. Under physics or particle system>field weights, mention the collection (the one you made) in Effector collection.